# Casting double* to int* in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, types, casting

The title's pretty self explanatory. I want to cast a type `double *` into a type `int *`. I realize that I can use the C-type cast `(int *)` to do what I want, but is there a way to do this cast using C++ type casting i.e. `static_cast` etc?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you want to turn a double into an int?

Comment: As other pointed you will not  cast a value this way. Even if it's not what you want, your code might not work because of strict aliasing rules.

Comment: Another way to do something similar is to make a union with a double and int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform this cast using a `reinterpret_cast`:

```
int* veryUnsafePointer = reinterpret_cast<int*>(myDoublePointer);
```

Be aware that this does not give you back an integer representation of the `double` being pointed at; instead, the integer's value will be dependent on the binary representation of the `double` and the endianness of the system.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So it seems you want to read the internal representation of a `double`. Do you know that a `double` is most likely larger than an `int`? (On most systems 8 vs. 4 bytes)

Comment: Dereferencing the result of this cast has undefined behavior because of the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/3425536).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `reinterpret_cast<int *>(ptr)`.

I hope you really know what you're doing though. There's very little reason to do such a cast, especially when it's likely a `double` and an `int` are different sizes.